# matplotlib.plot in Pyqt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm trying to embed plot in Pyqt5 widget and i found this class and it works but the range on the plot can be only from 0 to range(). I need plot that ranges from negative x. I tried modyfing it but failed. How could i do this?

```
class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.plot()


    def plot(self):
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        plot.plot(data, 'r-')
        plot.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        self.draw()
```

Comment: Normally matplotlib handles the plotting range pretty well. If not feeling satisfied, I would try to add `plot.set_xlim( min_x, max_x )` after `plot.plot(data, 'r-')` to manually assign the plot range.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you only need to modify your `plot()` function and use `plot.set_xlim()` like so:

```
...
...
    def plot(self):
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        plot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        plot.plot(data, 'r-')
        plot.set_xlim(left=-10) #<-- added here
        plot.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        self.draw()
```

And it generates this plot:

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis has been extended to include negative number starting from `-10`.